How to Handle Fetch Calls with Writable Stores in SvelteKit SSR without Eager Loading Warning
In the below snippets fetchPage($currentPage, $selectedOption); gets called on each page refresh as if that would be onMount(). I believe this is why I'm seeing following warning related to my Offers.svelte component:

Avoid calling fetch eagerly during server side rendering — put your
fetch calls inside onMount or a load function instead

I was initially thinking of movig fetchPage into load function of my +page.svelte file, but it wouldn't work because I need to use writable stores in few places in my code (not only as listed below).
Any suggestion, how could I resolve this warning?
store.ts
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const selectedOption = writable<Option>({'filter': ''});
export const currentPage = writable(1);

Pagination.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import { currentPage } from "./services/store.js";;
    export let goToNextPage: () => void;
</script>

<div class="pagination">
    <span>Page {$currentPage}</span>
    <button on:click={goToNextPage} class="btn">Next</button>
</div>

Offers.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import { selectedOption, currentPage } from "./services/store.js";
    import Pagination from "./Pagination.svelte";
    import { fetchFromDB } from "./services/api.js";

    let offers: Offer[] = [];
    let promise: Promise<any[]> = Promise.resolve([]);

    // Reactive statement to fetch data whenever currentPage or selectedOption changes
    $: if ($currentPage || $selectedOption) {
        fetchPage($currentPage, $selectedOption);
    }

    async function fetchPage(page: number, option: Option) {
        const { items } = await fetchFromDB(page,option);
        offers = items;
    }

    function goToNextPage() {
        if ($currentPage < 100) {
            $currentPage += 1;
        }
    }
</script>

{#await promise}
    Loading
{:then None}
    <div class="offers">
    {#each offers as offer (offer.id)}
                    {offer.area}
                {/each}
    </div>

    <Pagination {goToNextPage} />
{/await}

+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import Offers from "$lib/Offers.svelte";
</script>

<main>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-yellow-500">Projekt Hestia</h1>

  <div class="card">
    <Offers />
  </div>
</main>

